# mongoose pipeline does not work - $match does not work

Tags: mongoose

```
const { mustDo, size, taskName, taskCode } = data;

var query, variables: any, pipeLine, sampleSize;
variables = { checked: true };
if (mustDo != null) {
  variables.mustDo = mustDo;
}
if (taskName != null) {
  variables.taskName = taskName;
}
if (taskCode != null) {
  variables.taskCode = taskCode;
}
query = {
  $match: { $and: [variables] },
};

pipeLine = [];
pipeLine.push(query);

if (size != null) {
  sampleSize = { $sample: { size } };
  pipeLine.push(sampleSize);
}
console.log(pipeLine);

return await (await db)
  .collection("todo")
  .aggregate(pipeLine)
  .toArray();
```

I have this code but `$match` does not apply. I also tried with `$match: { $and: variables}`. Nothing seems to work. How can I create a $match in aggregate() when there are incoming values like this?